# termios are not available in linux server

Tags: python, linux, termios, python-3.9

I have a project that import termios and msvcrt to support Windows and Linux

In Windows, everything works fine, but in Linux when I test my project in python docker and also the main Linux server the following error occurred:

> NameError: name 'termios' is not defined

What should I do to support Linux?

[Sample Code](https://github.com/AliRezaBeigy/Gitools/tree/015da177f181d01b03501043fcb0082220ff8987)

Envierment:

- Python version: v3.9
- Linux distribution: Ubuntu

Comment: what code did you use? Show it in question (not in comment).

Comment: maybe check if Ubuntu doesn't have it as separated package in `apt-get`. It seems Ubuntu sometimes remove some elements from Python - for example on server it may not install `tkinter` which normally is installed with Python. Few hours ago someone said that Ubuntu may not have installed `pip` which normally is installed with Python.